# nodejs nock http get always returns 503

Tags: node.js, http, mocha.js, nock

I want to use nock for testing some http calls but it always retunrs 503 service unavailable

```
describe('BASIC API AUTH TESTS', function() {
  'use strict';

  before(async () => {
    if (!nock.isActive()) nock.activate();
  });

  after(async() => {
    nock.cleanAll();
    await helpers.removeTestUsers(mongoDb);
  });

it('should return nock response', async() => {
    if (!nock.isActive()) nock.activate();
    nock('http://zombo.com').get('/').times(1).reply(200, 'Ok');
    http.get('http://zombo.com/'); // expected 200 got 503 service unavailable
    console.log('nock.pendingMocks(): ', nock.pendingMocks()); //  [ 'GET http://zombo.com:80/' ]
  });
```

what is wrong?

testrunner: mocha
node version: 8.12
nock: 13.0.4

Comment: "The latest version of nock supports all currently maintained Node versions" ([source](https://github.com/nock/nock)). Maybe try with a newer Node version?

Comment: Can you clarify that the `http` variable is just the native HTTP module from Node?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is most likely related to the fact that you're not waiting for the request to respond (via Nock) before exiting the tests. Therefore `nock.cleanAll();` in your after block is removing your nock and the `http.get` is attempting a live call.

If you want to stick with native Node `http`, you need to ditch `async` (or get fancy with Promises). [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) have an example on how to use callbacks to wait for the response, then you can call the [Mocha `done` function](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).
If you want to stick with async, I recommend an HTTP client lib that support promises, then `await` the request.